# Blender 2.8 - eevee Silver/Chrome material

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

Attached is the blend where I am trying to add a silver/chrome material. I followed a few tutorials online but the material always looks dark and flat. I am just started to learn 2.8 so unable to figure this one out.

The mesh is lit with an area lamp and its placed on a plane for light reflection.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to add some extra details. Do you have lights / background / something to reflect on the object's surface?

Comment: Try to add same textures to your material

Comment: click on the shading workspace to get a good place to make materials.  the lighting is set up in a good way to test shaders, and their are a few hdris to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Activate "Screen Space Reflections" in the render tab. And may be you want to use my chnages to your shader. "Specular"s value "0.5" is more physically correct. I also cranked up the IOR value to 1.8, which is the IOR of silver (you will find huge tables
with IOR values for all kinds of materials online).

But the main reason, why the ring is dull grey in the "final" render and shiny in the viewport is: Your world material has the same dull grey color...:)
Even the most shiny silver ring will reflect only the dark when there is no light.
See attachment (the screenshot still has the wrong IOR...sorry)
[image]

Comment: This didn't work, but I ended up using HDRI maps.

Comment: You added light and it worked, therefore the answer absolutely worked and went betond to make it better than what you asked in the first place.